# Execute package failed in Sitecore Azure deployment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I have started the deployment of Editing farm and after some time got this error. Before that Databases are created in Azure.

```
Execute package failed System.ApplicationException: advaiyawebsiteDevScusCe01Role01SSc5e3Staging [S] 
 Execute package failed ---> System.ApplicationException: Execute package is failed ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 
 Build Package failed: Searching for imported module Caching at 
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\bin\plugins\Caching\Caching.csplugin... 
 Copying 'C:\InetPub\Sitecoredemo\Data\AzurePackages\(7) Azure\Sitecore.Azure.CacheWorkerRole' 
 to C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreCacheWorkerRole\approot... Copying 
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\bin\runtimes\base\x64' 
 to C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreCacheWorkerRole\base\x64... Copying 
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\bin\runtimes\base\x86' 
 to C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreCacheWorkerRole\base\x86... Copying 
 'C:\InetPub\Sitecoredemo\Data\AzurePackages\(7) Azure\SitecoreWebSite' to 
 C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreWebRole\approot... Copying 
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\bin\runtimes\base\x64' 
 to C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreWebRole\base\x64... Copying 
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\bin\runtimes\base\x86' 
 to C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreWebRole\base\x86... Copying 
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.5\bin\plugins\Caching' 
 to C:\Windows\TEMP\odbndccq.v4c\roles\SitecoreCacheWorkerRole\plugins\Caching... 
 UCPack_Command_Line: Error : CloudServices41 : The entrypoint Sitecore.Azure.CacheWorkerRole.dll is not a valid assembly. 
 Please provide a relative path to the binary that implements the entrypoint. 
 at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsFalse(Boolean condition, String message) 
 at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.CreateAzurePackage.Azure.ExecutePackage.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase arguments) 
 at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase args) 
 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have incorrect version of [Microsoft Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) installed.

- Sitecore Azure `8.0 rev. 150522` supports only version `2.5.1`
- Sitecore Azure `8.0 rev. 150522 Hotfix 68545-1` supports only version `2.7.1`
- Sitecore Azure `8.0 rev. 161110` supports only version `2.9.1`

For more details, please check the following article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/026831

Comment: I am using Sitecore Azure 8.0 rev. 150522 andI had installed Azure SDK version 2.5.1 only but it did'nt work. then i have installed Sitecore Azure 8.0 rev. 150522 Hotfix 68545-1 and Azure SDK 2.7.1 but now also it is giving the same error.